# Finder in Catalina Doesn't Show Thumbnails When Searching SD Card or External Drive

Tags: macos, finder, catalina, quicklook

Finder in Catalina doesn't show thumbnails when **searching** external drives or sd cards. It is challenging to find what you are looking for when you have a lot of photos or videos to look through.

What is needed to generate thumbnails on external media?

Answer (score 1):

What I do is use the Cover Flow view of files in the Finder. Open a Finder window. See image below.

Here is a folder with 6 photos in it. Notice the red rectangle in the top left of image. That determines your view. If you use the 4th selection, you can see the images.

[image]

Comment: i just didn't think of that.  Thanks for next time though.

Comment: I was answering the question in a before-and-after method.  1st image is before you chage the view. 2nd image is after.

Comment: Thanks.  That is what I've been doing, but I'm looking to see all of the icons in a larger format.